# Obtener un valor mínimo dependiento de otras columnas

Tags: mysql

Tengo  una tabla en una base de datos mysql de control de precios y stocks de productos por proveedor. Esta tabla se cumplimenta automáticamente desde otras tablas. La tabla tiene las siguientes columnas

- Referencia: Número de referencia del producto igual en todos los proveedores
- Coste pr.1 : Coste proveedor 1
- Coste pr.2 : Coste proveedor 2
- Coste pr.3 : Coste proveedor 3
- Stock pr. 1: Stock proveedor 1
- Stock pr. 2: Stock proveedor 2
- Stock pr. 3: Stock proveedor 3
- Stock To. : Stock total. Suma automática de todos los stocks
- Precio Min. con stock: Precio mínimo de coste con stock mayor que cero.

El problema lo tengo haciendo la consulta del Precio Min. con stock.

**Necesito hallar el precio mínimo de las tres columnas de coste siempre que el proveedor tenga stock.**

Estuve peleándome con la Función `MIN`, pero estoy atascado aquí.

*Trato de explicar el ejemplo siguiente.*

El proveedor 1 tiene un coste de 10  y un stock de 25, el proveedor 2 tiene un coste de 4 y un stock de 80 el proveedor 3 tiene un coste de 2 pero stock cero. La consulta en este caso tiene que resultarme 4, ya que es el precio mínimo con stock.

| Referencia | Coste pr. 1 | Coste pr. 2 | Coste pr. 3 | Stock pr. 1 | Stock pr. 2 | Stock pr. 3 | Stock To. | Precio Min. con stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 10 | 4 | 2 | 25 | 80 | 0 | 105 | 4 |

Comment: Por favor, muestra la consulta que has intentado hacer hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Si la tabla a la que haces referencia se llena con información de otras tablas, habría que ver la estructura de las otras tablas, quizas la query sea mas simple si obtienes la información directamente de la tabla original.

Una opción es utilizar 3 subqueries para obtener la referencia y el precio de cada producto de cada uno de los proveedores con stock mayor a cero, luego se agrupa por Referencia (producto) y se obtiene el mínimo costo:

```
SELECT Referencia, MIN(Coste) AS PrecioMinConStock
FROM (
       (SELECT Referencia, CostePr1 AS Coste FROM t WHERE StockPr1 > 0)

       UNION ALL

       (SELECT Referencia, CostePr2 AS Coste FROM t WHERE StockPr2 > 0)

       UNION ALL

       (SELECT Referencia, CostePr3 AS Coste FROM t WHERE StockPr3 > 0)) AS sq
       
GROUP BY Referencia;
```

Otra opción, sin utilizar subqueries, podría ser utilizando la sentencia `CASE` anidada.

No conozco tu modelo de datos, pero a primera vista esa tabla no parece la mejor opción (parece que estás almacenando información duplicada, ya que la misma se encuentra en otras tablas según entendí, además dicha tabla no se encuentra normalizada), quizas deberías reevaluar el mismo y buscar otras soluciones.